# Is there a way to sort a numbered list automatically?

Tags: lists, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort an alphanumeric list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6988/how-to-sort-an-alphanumeric-list)

For example, I have the following code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Rabbit
  \item Apple
  \item Serpent
\end{enumerate}
```

Is there a way to add something to this and get a sorted, numbered list as output?

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6988/how-to-sort-an-alphanumeric-list There the issue is solved in multiple different ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a comma delimited list and then sort it. Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lstdoc,booktabs}
\makeatletter
\let\alist\@empty

\def\addtolist#1{%
    \lst@lAddTo\alist{#1,}
    \lst@BubbleSort{\alist} 
}

\parindent0pt
\newcounter{cnt}
\setcounter{cnt}{0}
\begin{document}


%% adding the data now
\addtolist{banana}  
\addtolist{zero}
\addtolist{apple}  
\addtolist{arab}

\@for\next:=\alist\do{%
   \stepcounter{cnt}%
   \thecnt\space \next\\
}
\end{document}
```

You can format the output within the `\@for` loop.

Comment: It looks good. But it prints an empty line at the end ("5") for me. And will it be possible to make several sorted lists in one document?

Comment: @Rogach Thanks, will add a more complete solution late in the evening. Anything is possible in TeX.