# Alphabetically display the items in itemize

Tags: glossaries, itemize, sorting

I am wondering whether it is possible to display the items alphabetically regardless of the order we type on the backend? For example I am using itemize as follows:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item ISDYNSTP:  Is dynamic time step used?
    \item ISCDCA:
    \item MVAR
    \item IS2TL_
\end{itemize}
```

But I want to display the items in the alphabetical order. I don't know whether it is possible or not. I have like hundreds of itemize items. Actually I am trying to create a glossary for the different parameters.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Taking some code from [How to sort an alphanumeric list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6988/5764), a mild change to your interface works for sorting via the [`datatool` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}% http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool
\newcommand{\sortitem}[1]{%
  \DTLnewrow{list}% Create a new entry
  \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#1}% Add entry as description
}
\newenvironment{sortedlist}{%
  \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}% Create new/discard old list
}{%
  \DTLsort{description}{list}% Sort list
  \begin{itemize}%
    \DTLforeach*{list}{\theDesc=description}{%
      \item \theDesc}% Print each item
  \end{itemize}%
}
\begin{document}

Default:
\begin{itemize}
  \item ISDYNSTP:  Is dynamic time step used ?
  \item ISCDCA:
  \item MVAR
  \item IS2TL
\end{itemize}

Sorted:
\begin{sortedlist}
  \sortitem{ISDYNSTP:  Is dynamic time step used ?}
  \sortitem{ISCDCA:}
  \sortitem{MVAR}
  \sortitem{IS2TL}
\end{sortedlist}

\end{document}
```

---

To allow for formatting of sorted elements, it's best to modify the syntax. To that end, the following MWE supplied an updated version of `\sortitem[<sort label>]{<label/description>}` that takes an optional `<sort label>` (used as the label to sort upon):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}% http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool
\newcommand{\sortitem}[2][\relax]{%
  \DTLnewrow{list}% Create a new entry
  \ifx#1\relax
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{sortlabel}{#2}% Add entry sortlabel (no optional argument)
  \else
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{sortlabel}{#1}% Add entry sortlabel (optional argument)
  \fi%
  \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#2}% Add entry description
}
\newenvironment{sortedlist}{%
  \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}% Create new/discard old list
}{%
  \DTLsort{sortlabel}{list}% Sort list
  \begin{itemize}%
    \DTLforeach*{list}{\theDesc=description}{%
      \item \theDesc}% Print each item
  \end{itemize}%
}
\begin{document}

Default:
\begin{itemize}
  \item ISDYNSTP:  Is dynamic time step used ?
  \item ISCDCA:
  \item MVAR
  \item IS2TL
\end{itemize}

Sorted:
\begin{sortedlist}
  \sortitem{ISDYNSTP:  Is dynamic time step used ?}
  \sortitem[ISCDCA]{\textit{ISCDCA:}}
  \sortitem[MVAR]{\textbf{MVAR}}
  \sortitem{IS2TL}
\end{sortedlist}

\end{document}
```

---

If you want a **case-insensitive** comparison, just replace the `\DTLsort` command by `\DTLsort*`.

Comment: Werner, I have a quick question here. Whenever I try to bold the first word on the itemize, it automatically goes to the first in the sortedlist. Is there any way I can automatically change the first word to be bold ?

Comment: @Jdbaba: See my updated post, which now provides `\sortitem[<sort label>]{<label/description>}`, allowing you to supply a different label to sort on from the description. This is very commonly done when sorting is involved, since you could use macros that don't have any relevant sorting reference.

Comment: @ Werner: thank you for this addition. This works perfect. I wish I could double vote.

Comment: @Werner: This is an awesome idea (wish I had thought of it). But and having some difficulty in using it and can't quite figure out what is going on. With `Sorted 2:
\begin{sortedlist}
  \sortitem{foo}
  \sortitem{abc}
  \sortitem[yyx]{\textbf{yyx}}
\end{sortedlist}` I get two issues: 1. The title line appears as `Sorted 2:   x` (not sure where the `x` is coming from) and 2. `yyz` appears first?  The spacing betwen the title and the `x` depends on the number of `\sortitem`s.  [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/3Sa2bqx).

Comment: Seems that there is some issue with having an optional parameter in `\sortitem`. If I make it have two mandatory parameters (and adjust the definition), things work just fine.  It seems that the `x` in the output seems to any characters _after_ the first two `yy` in the optional parameter. So, using `yyz4` as the first parameter, results in the title being `Sorted 2: z4`.  You can simply replace `[MVAR]` in your example with `[yyMVAR]` to see this problem.

Comment: How should I modify that template to replace `itemize` with `description`?

Comment: @M.Dudek: `description` mostly requires `\item`s to have an optional argument. My implementation uses the optional argument to `\sortitem` to influence the sorting, so the entire approach will have to be updated. I suggest posting a new, [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764) to request that.