# Changing the Hanging Indent Within a Custom Environment

Tags: indentation

The hanging indent for my sorted entries (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121492/54839)) is seemingly unchangeable, I've tried placing `\hangindent`'s and `\hangafter`'s all over the place and nothing seems to change what looks like a half inch hanging indent, which is way to large.

I initially thought that maybe `multicol` package was to blame, but even with it disabled the indent is still the same.

Preferably I'd want around 12pt hanging indent to save space because I don't need the separate entries standing out *that* much.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{datatool}

%Command Setups

\newcommand{\wn}[5]{%
    \DTLnewrow{list}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{label}{#1}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{\textit{\textsc{{\footnotesize n.}}} \textbf{#2} }
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{ipa}{(#3) }%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{plural}{\textit{pl.\hspace{2pt}#4 }}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{extra}{#5}%
}
\newcommand{\wv}[4]{%
    \DTLnewrow{list}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{label}{#1}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{\textit{\textsc{{\footnotesize v.}}} \textbf{#2} }
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{ipa}{(#3) }%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{plural}{}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{extra}{#4}%
}
\newcommand{\wa}[4]{%
    \DTLnewrow{list}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{label}{#1}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{\textit{\textsc{{\footnotesize adj.}}} \textbf{#2} }
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{ipa}{(#3) }%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{plural}{}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{extra}{#4}%
}

%Enviroment Setup

\newenvironment{sortedlist}%
{%
    \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}%
}%
{%
    \DTLsort{label}{list}%
    \begin{description}%
        \DTLforeach*{list}{\theLabel=label,\theDesc=description,\theIp=ipa,\thePl=plural,\theEx=extra}{%
            \markboth{\theLabel}{\theLabel}%
            \item[\theLabel] \theDesc \theIp \thePl \theEx
        }%
    \end{description}% 
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\textsc{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\textsc{\leftmark}}

\begin{multicols}{2}\hangindent=1pt\setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}
\raggedright
\begin{sortedlist}
    \wn{Lorem}{ipsum}{dolor}{amet}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.}
    \wa{Lorem}{ipsum}{amet}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.}
    \wv{Lorem}{ipsum}{amet}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.}
\end{sortedlist}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a `description` environment, it is better to load `enumitem` package and adjust `leftmargin`:

```
\begin{description}[leftmargin=3em]
```

in the definition of `sortedlist`.

```
\newenvironment{sortedlist}%
{%
    \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}%
}%
{%
    \DTLsort{label}{list}%
    \begin{description}[leftmargin=3em]%
        \DTLforeach*{list}{\theLabel=label,\theDesc=description,\theIp=ipa,\thePl=plural,\theEx=extra}{%
            \markboth{\theLabel}{\theLabel}%
            \item[\theLabel] \theDesc \theIp \thePl \theEx
        }%
    \end{description}%
}
```

Adjust 3em as you wish.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%Command Setups

\newcommand{\wn}[5]{%
    \DTLnewrow{list}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{label}{#1}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{\textit{\textsc{{\footnotesize n.}}} \textbf{#2} }
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{ipa}{(#3) }%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{plural}{\textit{pl.\hspace{2pt}#4 }}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{extra}{#5}%
}
\newcommand{\wv}[4]{%
    \DTLnewrow{list}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{label}{#1}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{\textit{\textsc{{\footnotesize v.}}} \textbf{#2} }
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{ipa}{(#3) }%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{plural}{}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{extra}{#4}%
}
\newcommand{\wa}[4]{%
    \DTLnewrow{list}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{label}{#1}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{\textit{\textsc{{\footnotesize adj.}}} \textbf{#2} }
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{ipa}{(#3) }%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{plural}{}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{extra}{#4}%
}

%Enviroment Setup

\newenvironment{sortedlist}%
{%
    \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}%
}%
{%
    \DTLsort{label}{list}%
    \begin{description}[leftmargin=3em]%
        \DTLforeach*{list}{\theLabel=label,\theDesc=description,\theIp=ipa,\thePl=plural,\theEx=extra}{%
            \markboth{\theLabel}{\theLabel}%
            \item[\theLabel] \theDesc \theIp \thePl \theEx
        }%
    \end{description}%
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\textsc{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\textsc{\leftmark}}

\begin{multicols}{2}\setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}
\raggedright
\begin{sortedlist}
    \wn{Lorem}{ipsum}{dolor}{amet}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.}
    \wa{Lorem}{ipsum}{amet}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.}
    \wv{Lorem}{ipsum}{amet}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.}
\end{sortedlist}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `leftmargin=1em` we get

[image]

There are other lengths too that can be adjusted using `enumitem`. For details, please refer to the manual.