# Sorting a list alphabetically by a Macro output

Tags: glossaries, itemize, sorting

this is an extended question taken by [Alphabetically display the items in itemize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121489/alphabetically-display-the-items-in-itemize/121492#121492)

The solution posted by Werner is amazing. But what I need is to sort by a value of a macro.
For example `\foo{Label}` is a function that take Label as argument and give you SortLabel as string.

```
\foo{Label1} %Will print SortLabel1
\foo{Label2} %Will print SortLabel2    
\foo{Label3} %Will print SortLabel3

\begin{sortedlist}
    \sortitem[\foo{Label1}]{Bar1}
    \sortitem[\foo{Label2}]{Bar2}
    \sortitem[\foo{Label3}]{Bar3}
\end{sortedlist}
```

Tryed to use `\expandafter`, but seems that datatool can store only by `\foo{Label1}` and can't sort for `SortLabel1`....

To be more specific, the function `\foo` for me is `\glossentryname{}` that give me the name of a glossary entry. Maybe this could be the reason that expansion doesn't work. Here's a MnWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}% http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool
\usepackage{glossaries, glossary-tree}
\makeglossaries

%%%%Sorted Functions%%%%
\newcommand{\sortitem}[1]{%
  \DTLnewrow{list}% Create a new entry
  \def\tmp{\DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}}%
  \expandafter\tmp\expandafter{#1}% Add entry as description
}
\newenvironment{sortedlist}{%
  \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}% Create new/discard old list
}{%
  \DTLsort{description}{list}% Sort list
  \begin{itemize}%
    \DTLforeach*{list}{\theDesc=description}{%
      \item \theDesc}% Print each item
  \end{itemize}%
}

%%%The Glossary Part%%%%%
\longnewglossaryentry{MVARglossary}{name=MVAR}{
The Description of glossary (not useful at the moment)
}


\begin{document}

Default:
\begin{itemize}
  \item ISDYNSTP:  Is dynamic time step used ?
  \item ISCDCA:
  \item MVAR
  \item IS2TL
\end{itemize}

\def\foo{ISDYNSTP:  Is dynamic time step used ?}
\def\bar{\glossaryname{MVARglossary}}

\glossentryname{MVARglossary}

\bar

Sorted:
\begin{sortedlist}
  \sortitem{\foo}
  \sortitem{ISCDCA:}
  \sortitem{\bar}
  \sortitem{\glossentryname{MVARglossary}}
  \sortitem{IS2TL}
\end{sortedlist}

\end{document}
```

suggests?

Comment: `\glossentryname` isn't expandable, so it's going to be hard to sort `\glossentryname{MVARglossary}`.

Comment: What about `\gls{}`?

Comment: No, only the [`\glsentry`*fieldname* commands](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:glsnolink). (Not the case changing variants like `\Glsentryname` or `\glsentrytitlecase`, just the ones like `\glsentryname` or `\glsentrytext`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I modified Werner's solution by editing `\sortitem` as

```
\newcommand{\sortitem}[1]{%
  \DTLnewrow{list}% Create a new entry
  \def\tmp{\DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}}%
  \expandafter\tmp\expandafter{#1}% Add entry as description
}
```

in order to expand the argument being processed.  Then, in the MWE, I can pass `\foo` as an item to be sorted (where `\foo` is a definition unrelated to glossary entry names).

The next problem was that `\glossentryname` is not expandable.  So I employed the existing `\glsentryname` macro instead (originally, I had made a limited version of `\glossentryname`, that is expandable, but Nicola pointed out that also plays with the font).  I then created a macro `\sortgloss{<label>}` that will invoke `\sortitem` on the expanded gloss-entry-name.

Here is the MWE (EDITED to take Nicola's suggestion at using the existing expandable `\glsentryname` rather than create a new expandable macro)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{datatool}% http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sortitem}[1]{%
  \DTLnewrow{list}% Create a new entry
  \def\tmp{\DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}}%
  \expandafter\tmp\expandafter{#1}% Add entry as description
}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{sortedlist}{%
  \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}% Create new/discard old list
}{%
  \DTLsort{description}{list}% Sort list
  \begin{itemize}%
    \DTLforeach*{list}{\theDesc=description}{%
      \item \theDesc}% Print each item
  \end{itemize}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\sortgloss[1]{%
  \protected@edef\x@glossname{\glsentryname{#1}}%
  \sortitem{\x@glossname}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Default:
\begin{itemize}
  \item ISDYNSTP:  Is dynamic time step used ?
  \item ISCDCA:
  \item MVAR
  \item IS2TL
\end{itemize}

\newacronym{MVx}{MVAR}{Many Virgins Act Responsibly}


\def\foo{ISDYNSTP:  Is dynamic time step used ?}

Sorted:
\begin{sortedlist}
  \sortitem{\foo}
  \sortitem{ISCDCA:}
  \sortgloss{MVx}
  \sortitem{IS2TL}
\end{sortedlist}


\end{document}
```

The output is the same as Werner's:

[image]

Alternately, if one were to define `\sortitem` to fully expand its argument:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sortitem}[1]{%
  \DTLnewrow{list}% Create a new entry
  \protected@edef\tmpA{#1}%
  \def\tmp{\DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}}%
  \expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\tmpA}% Add entry as description
}
\makeatother
```

then one would be free to invoke it as `\sortitem{\glsentryname{MVx}}` rather than `\sortgloss{MVx}`, if consistency of invocation syntax were important.

Comment: Thank you! I've edited my question with a Minimal NonWorking Example, because it seems not working with `\glossentryname{}` .

Comment: @AlbertoVerdoja I have compiled a revised version that may be of use.

Comment: `\Glossentryname` is already defined in `glossaries.sty`. Why not just use [`\glsentryname`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:glsnolink) (which is expandable) instead?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Oops!  I will correct it.  Thanks!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sorry, I meant that `\glsentryname` is an existing expandable command, so it works better for sorting (without the font-changing `\glsnamefont`). Actually, perhaps it would be better to access the `sort` key for the entry, which would make more sense, but then you'd have to separate out the sort key and the displayed text.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Double-oops!  I just deleted my (re)definition of `\glsentryname` and found, as you indicate, that the existing `\glsentryname` works just fine with my `\sortgloss` macro.  I hope I have accomplished your intent.  I am not a `glossaries` user and so don't feel comfortable expanding the answer to use sort keys and such.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That's fine +1 :-) (Perhaps use `\protected@xdef` instead of `\xdef`?) The sort key would only be needed if the name was a symbol or something involving non-expandable commands, which isn't the case here.