# How to create an alphabetical attachment list that supports unicode characters?

Tags: table-of-contents, biber, unicode, sorting, lua

I would like to be able to create a list of attachments similar to the list of figures or tables. However, since it makes little sense to sort the attachments by page number, I would like to sort them alphabetically.

I can create the list of attachments itself, but I'm having trouble sorting it alphabetically. I saw that it was possible to do it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307858/sorting-a-list-alphabetically-by-a-macro-output). However, this solution does not work for me (with PdfLatex it works, but with LuaLatex, which I use, the classification is wrong):
[image] [image]

So I was wondering if it was possible to use Lua directly or to use the power of Biber (outside the context of Biblatex) to alphabetize a list containing unicode characters. Wouldn't these tools be more efficient in this field?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref, embedfile, hypgotoe, datatool}

\renewcommand*{\dtlsetUTFviiicharcode}[2]{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{À}{#2=65\relax}%
        {\ifstrequal{#1}{É}{#2=69\relax}{\dtlsetdefaultUTFviiicharcode{#1}{#2}}}%
}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\declareattachedfile}{m m}{%
    \embedfile[ucfilespec={#2.pdf}]{#1}%
    \addtocontents{loaf}{%
            \protect\DTLnewrow{listofattachedfiles}%
            \protect\DTLnewdbentry{listofattachedfiles}{filename}{#1}%      
            \protect\DTLnewdbentry{listofattachedfiles}{filetitle}{#2}%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\listofattachedfiles}{%
    \section*{List of attached files}%
    \DTLnewdb{listofattachedfiles}%
    \@starttoc{loaf}%
    \DTLsort{filetitle}{listofattachedfiles}%
    \DTLforeach*{listofattachedfiles}{\theFiletitle=filetitle, \theFilename=filename}{%
        \vskip 12\p@ \@plus\p@%
        \begingroup%
            \noindent\href[pdfnewwindow=true]{gotoe:embedded=\theFilename}{\theFiletitle}%
            \par%
        \endgroup%
    }%
    \newpage%
}
\makeatother

\declareattachedfile{example-image-letter-numbered.pdf}{Z}
\declareattachedfile{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}{A}
\declareattachedfile{example-image.pdf}{1}
\declareattachedfile{example-image-a.pdf}{É}
\declareattachedfile{example-image-b.pdf}{N}

\begin{document}
\listofattachedfiles

Expected sorting :
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item A
\item É
\item N
\item Z
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you naturally could use biber. You would have to store your file names etc as bib-entries and write a suitable bibliography driver.  To sort with lua see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344151/2388