# How to order alphabetically the items in the itemize environment?

Tags: itemize, alphabet

I have a really long list in an itemize environment and I want to order it in alphabetical order. My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,openright,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel} %Defino idioma como español
\usepackage{graphicx} % Para Añadir imagenes
\usepackage{subfigure} %Para las subfiguras
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[spanish,onelanguage]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\section*{Glosario}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
\setlength\itemsep{0.00em}
%\small
\item \textbf{DD.HH:} Derechos Humanos
\item \textbf{LH:} Logística Humanitaria
\item \textbf{OMS:} Organización Mundial de la Salud
\item \textbf{ONU:} Organización de las Naciones Unidas
\item \textbf{WFP:} \textit{World Food Programme}
\item \textbf{FIDA:} Fondo Internacional de Desarrollo Agrícola
\item \textbf{ECHO:} \textit{European Civil Protection and Humanitarian Aid Operations}
\item \textbf{CICR:} Comité Internacional de la Cruz Roja
\item \textbf{ONEMI:} Oficina Nacional de Emergencias del Ministerio del Interior
\item \textbf{IO:} Investigación de Operaciones
\item \textbf{OFDA:} Oficina de Asistencia para Desastres del Gobierno de los Estados Unidos, América Latina y el Caribe.
\item \textbf{CRED:} Centro de Investigación sobre la Epidemiología de los Desastres
\item \textbf{NSGA:} \textit{Non-dominated Sorting Genetic Algorithm}
\item \textbf{SPEA:} \textit{Strength Pareto Evolutionary Algorithm}
\item \textbf{ONU:} Organización de las Naciones Unidas
\item \textbf{ACNUR:} Alto Comisionado de las Naciones Unidas para los Refugiados
\item \textbf{AG:} Algoritmos Genéticos
\item \textbf{CONAF:} Corporación Nacional Forestal
\item \textbf{CONASET:} Comisión Nacional de Seguridad de Tránsito
\item \textbf{SNPC:} Servicio Nacional del Patrimonio Cultural
\item \textbf{SIDCO:} Sistema de Información Digital para Control de Desastres
\item \textbf{PIB:} Producto Interno Bruto
\item \textbf{MINSAL:} Ministerio de Salud
\item \textbf{SRT:} \textit{Standar Relief Time}
\item \textbf{CAL:} Centro de Acopio Local
\item \textbf{LS:}  Logística de Socorro
\item \textbf{LD:}  Logística de Desarrollo
\item \textbf{UNISDR:} \textit{United Nations Office for Disaster Risk Reduction}
\item \textbf{ONG:} Organización no Gubernamental
\item \textbf{VRP:} \textit{Vehicle routing problem}
\item \textbf{PDSTSP:} \textit{Parallel Drone Scheduling Traveling Salesman Problem}
\item \textbf{TSP:} \textit{Traveling Salesman Problem}
\item \textbf{VIH:} Virus de Inmunodeficiencia Humana
\item \textbf{SIDA:} Síndrome de Inmunodeficiencia Adquirida
\item \textbf{ACO:} \textit{Ant Colony Optimization}
\item \textbf{MPE:} Métodos de Programación Entera
\item \textbf{VNS:} \textit{Variable Neighborhood Search}
\item \textbf{MTZ-SEC's:} Miller-Tucker-Zemlin Subtour Elimination Constraints
\item \textbf{CLT:} Costo Logístico Total
\item \textbf{CTT:} Costo de Transporte Total
\item \textbf{CIT:} Costo de Instalación Total
\item \textbf{CAT:} Costo de Asignación Total
\item \textbf{CDIT:} Costo por Demanda Insatisfecha Total
\item \textbf{C:} Camiones
\item \textbf{H:} Helicópteros
\item \textbf{m-p:} Múltiples productos
\item \textbf{m-v:} Múltiples vehículos
\item \textbf{m-d:} Múltiples depósitos
\item \textbf{s-d:} \textit{Split Delivery}
\item \textbf{t-l:} Tiempo de circulación limitado
\item \textbf{MO:} Múltiples Objetivos
\item \textbf{TPDRO:} \textit{Transportation Problem in Disaster Response Operations}

\end{itemize}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

How can I do this? any ideas?. Thanks and advance and greetings.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121492/184389) might help you.

Comment: latex has no standard way of doing this, normally you would just sort the lines in your editor.