# Sort \begin{abbreviations} in alphabetical order?

Tags: lists, acronyms

I am using the `\begin{abbreviations}` function for my thesis. Is there a way to automatically sort them in alphabetical order?

Thanks in advance :)

```
\newcommand{\abbrevname}{List of Abbreviations}
\providecaptionname{english,british,american}{\abbrevname}{List of Abbreviations}
\providecaptionname{ngerman,german,austrian,naustrian}{\abbrevname}{Abk\"urzungsverzeichnis}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{abbreviations}{ m }{%
    \ifbool{nolistspace}{\begingroup\singlespacing}{}
    \ifbool{listtoc}{\addchap{\abbrevname}}{\addchap*{\abbrevname}}
    \begin{longtable}{#1}
    }{%
    \end{longtable}
    \addtocounter{table}{-1}% Don't count this table as one of the document tables
    \ifbool{nolistspace}{\endgroup}{}
}
```

Comment: My abbreviations are separated by \\

Comment: What package or class provides this environment? Perhaps this helps? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121489/2693

Comment: An even more useful link: [Modifying existing code to sort a list of abbreviations](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/86320)