# Improving TikZ potatoes

Tags: tikz-pgf

My aim is to provide tools to draw some irregular shapes more easily. Of course, I am aware of the smooth plots provided by Ti*k*Z but my aim is to make to allow for an alternative approach. Very often, the shapes are more or less defined by some extreme points, at which the distance to the barycenter of the shape is extremal (examples come below). I was able to get some shapes but only at the expense of borrowing routines from some other places, which I quote, and these routines appear to be more complex than necessarily needed. Further, my code only treats 4 coordinates. In principle, I now how to extend it but I feel I should simplify things before. This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\makeatletter % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283273/121799
% Here we define the comparison macro for pairs (a,b)
% We assume decimal numbers acceptable to \ifdim tests
\long\def\xintdothis #1#2\xintorthat #3{\fi #1}%
\let\xintorthat \@firstofone

\long\def\@thirdoffour  #1#2#3#4{#3}%
\long\def\@fourthoffour #1#2#3#4{#4}%

\def\IfFirstPairIsGreaterTF #1#2{\@IfFirstPairIsGreaterTF #1,#2,}%

\def\@IfFirstPairIsGreaterTF #1,#2,#3,#4,{%
    \ifdim #1\p@=#3\p@
       \xintdothis{%
         \ifdim #2\p@>#4\p@\expandafter\@firstoftwo
         \else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}\fi
    \ifdim #1\p@>#3\p@\expandafter\@thirdoffour
                      \else\expandafter\@fourthoffour\fi
    \xintorthat{}%
}%

% not needed for numerical inputs
% \catcode`! 3
% \catcode`? 3

% Here there is a very strange \romannumeral0\romannumeral0, this is
% due to some convoluted scheme to avoid double spaces or no spaces
% in between coordinate pairs. Trust me.
\def\QSpairs {\romannumeral0\romannumeral0\qspairs }%
% first we check if empty list
\def\qspairs   #1{\expandafter\qspairs@a\romannumeral-`0#1(!)(?)}%
\def\qspairs@a #1(#2{\ifx!#2\expandafter\qspairs@abort\else
                        \expandafter\qspairs@b\fi (#2}%
\edef\qspairs@abort #1(?){\space\space}%
%
% we check if empty of single and if not pick up the first as Pivot:
\def\qspairs@b #1(#2)#3(#4){\ifx?#4\xintdothis\qspairs@empty\fi
                   \ifx!#4\xintdothis\qspairs@single\fi
                   \xintorthat \qspairs@separate {}{}{#2}(#4)}%
\def\qspairs@empty  #1(?){ }%
\edef\qspairs@single #1#2#3#4(?){\space\space(#3)}%
\def\qspairs@separate #1#2#3#4(#5)%
{%
    \ifx!#5\expandafter\qspairs@separate@done\fi
    \IfFirstPairIsGreaterTF {#5}{#3}%
          \qspairs@separate@appendtogreater
          \qspairs@separate@appendtosmaller {#5}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}%
%
\def\qspairs@separate@appendtogreater #1#2{\qspairs@separate {#2 (#1)}}%
\def\qspairs@separate@appendtosmaller #1#2#3{\qspairs@separate {#2}{#3 (#1)}}%
%
\def\qspairs@separate@done\IfFirstPairIsGreaterTF #1#2%
    \qspairs@separate@appendtogreater
    \qspairs@separate@appendtosmaller #3#4#5#6(?)%
{%
    \expandafter\qspairs@f\expandafter
    {\romannumeral0\qspairs@b #4(!)(?)}{\qspairs@b #5(!)(?)}{ (#2)}%
}%
%
\def\qspairs@f #1#2#3{#2#3#1}%
%
% \catcode`! 12
% \catcode`? 12

\makeatother
\makeatletter % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412901/121799
\newcommand{\Distance}[3]{% % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56353/121799
\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone($#1-#2$)\relax  
\pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{veclen(\the\pgf@x,\the\pgf@y)/28.45274}
}
\makeatother 
\newcount\nbofwords
\makeatletter% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12819/121799
\def\myutil@empty{}
\def\multiwords#1 #2\@nil{% 
 \def\NextArg{#2}%
 \advance\nbofwords by  1 %   
 \expandafter\edef\csname word\@alph\nbofwords\endcsname{#1}% 
 \ifx\myutil@empty\NextArg
     \let\next\@gobble
 \fi
 \next#2\@nil
}%    
\def\GetWords#1{%
   \let\next\multiwords 
   \nbofwords=0 %
   \expandafter\next#1 \@nil %
}% 
\makeatother

\long\def\First(#1,#2){#1}
\long\def\Second(#1,#2){#2}
\tikzset{declare
function={interpolator(\x,\xmin,\xmax,\rmin,\rmax)=(\rmin+\rmax)/2+((\rmin-\rmax)/2)*cos((\x-\xmin)*(180/(\xmax-\xmin)));}}
%\tikzset{declare function={PotatoeRadius(\x,\angleA,\angleB,\angleC,\angleD,\distanceA,\distanceB,\distanceC,\distanceD)=\distanceA+(\x-\angleA)*((\distanceB-\distanceA)/(\angleB-\angleA)+(\x-\angleB)*(((-1)*((\distanceB-\distanceA)/(\angleB-\angleA))+(\distanceC-\distanceB)/(\angleC-\angleB))/(\angleC-\angleA)+(((-1)*(((-1)*((\distanceB-\distanceA)/(\angleB-\angleA))+(\distanceC-\distanceB)/(\angleC-\angleB))/(\angleC-\angleA))+((-1)*((\distanceC-\distanceB)/(\angleC-\angleB))+(\distanceD-\distanceC)/(\angleD-\angleC))/(\angleD-\angleB))*(\x-\angleC))/(\angleD-\angleA)));}}
%(\angleC*(\angleC-\angleD)*\angleD*((\distanceA-\distanceB)*(\angleC-\x)*(\angleD-\x)*\x+pow(\angleA,3)*(-(\angleC*pow(\angleD,2)*\distanceB)+\angleD*(\distanceB-\distanceC)*(\angleD-\x)*\x+\angleC*(\distanceB-\distanceD)*pow(\x,2)+pow(\angleC,2)*(\angleD*\distanceB+(-\distanceB+\distanceD)*\x))+pow(\angleB,3)*(-(\angleA*pow(\angleD,2)*\distanceC)-\angleD*(\distanceA-\distanceC)*(\angleD-\x)*\x+\angleA*(\distanceC-\distanceD)*pow(\x,2)+pow(\angleC,2)*(-(\angleD*\distanceA)+\angleA*\distanceD+\distanceA*\x-\distanceD*\x)+pow(\angleA,2)*(\angleD*\distanceC-\distanceC*\x+\distanceD*\x)+\angleC*(pow(\angleD,2)*\distanceA-pow(\angleA,2)*\distanceD+(-\distanceA+\distanceD)*pow(\x,2)))+pow(\angleA,2)*(-(\angleD*(\distanceB-\distanceC)*(\angleD-\x)*\x*(\angleD+\x))-pow(\angleC,3)*(\angleD*\distanceB+(-\distanceB+\distanceD)*\x)+\angleC*(pow(\angleD,3)*\distanceB+(-\distanceB+\distanceD)*pow(\x,3)))+\angleA*(pow(\angleD,2)*(\distanceB-\distanceC)*(\angleD-\x)*pow(\x,2)+pow(\angleC,3)*(pow(\angleD,2)*\distanceB+(-\distanceB+\distanceD)*pow(\x,2))-pow(\angleC,2)*(pow(\angleD,3)*\distanceB+(-\distanceB+\distanceD)*pow(\x,3)))+pow(\angleB,2)*(\angleD*(\distanceA-\distanceC)*(\angleD-\x)*\x*(\angleD+\x)+pow(\angleC,3)*(\angleD*\distanceA-\angleA*\distanceD-\distanceA*\x+\distanceD*\x)-pow(\angleA,3)*(\angleD*\distanceC+(-\distanceC+\distanceD)*\x)+\angleC*(-(pow(\angleD,3)*\distanceA)+pow(\angleA,3)*\distanceD+(\distanceA-\distanceD)*pow(\x,3))+\angleA*(pow(\angleD,3)*\distanceC+(-\distanceC+\distanceD)*pow(\x,3)))+\angleB*(-(pow(\angleD,2)*(\distanceA-\distanceC)*(\angleD-\x)*pow(\x,2))+pow(\angleC,3)*(-(pow(\angleD,2)*\distanceA)+pow(\angleA,2)*\distanceD+(\distanceA-\distanceD)*pow(\x,2))+pow(\angleA,3)*(pow(\angleD,2)*\distanceC+(-\distanceC+\distanceD)*pow(\x,2))+pow(\angleC,2)*(pow(\angleD,3)*\distanceA-pow(\angleA,3)*\distanceD+(-\distanceA+\distanceD)*pow(\x,3))-pow(\angleA,2)*(pow(\angleD,3)*\distanceC+(-\distanceC+\distanceD)*pow(\x,3))))/((\angleA-\angleB)*(\angleA-\angleC)*(\angleB-\angleC)*(\angleA-\angleD)*(\angleB-\angleD)*(\angleC-\angleD)));}}
\newcommand{\DrawArcAngle}[6][]{% just for emergencies
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
\xdef\angleA{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#4}{center}}
\xdef\angleB{\pgfmathresult}
\draw[#1] ($(#3)+(\angleA:#5)$) arc [start angle=\angleA,end angle=\angleB,radius=#5]
#6;
}
\newcommand{\DrawPotato}[5][]{
\coordinate (PotatoCenter) at (barycentric cs:#2=1,#3=1,#4=1,#5=1);
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{PotatoCenter}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
\xdef\angleA{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{PotatoCenter}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}}
\xdef\angleB{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{PotatoCenter}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#4}{center}}
\xdef\angleC{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{PotatoCenter}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#5}{center}}
\xdef\angleD{\pgfmathresult}

\Distance{(PotatoCenter)}{(#2)}{\distanceA}
\Distance{(PotatoCenter)}{(#3)}{\distanceB}
\Distance{(PotatoCenter)}{(#4)}{\distanceC}
\Distance{(PotatoCenter)}{(#5)}{\distanceD}
\xdef\coordList{(\angleA,\distanceA) (\angleB,\distanceB) (\angleC,\distanceC) (\angleD,\distanceD)}%
\typeout{\coordList}
\xdef\sortedList{\QSpairs{\coordList}}%
\GetWords{\sortedList}
\xdef\NewList{\worda,\wordb,\wordc,\wordd}%
\xdef\NewList{\expandafter\First\worda/\expandafter\Second\worda, 
\expandafter\First\wordb/\expandafter\Second\wordb,
\expandafter\First\wordc/\expandafter\Second\wordc,
\expandafter\First\wordd/\expandafter\Second\wordd}% this list is not used
\xdef\angleA{\expandafter\First\worda}%
\xdef\distanceA{\expandafter\Second\worda}%
\xdef\angleB{\expandafter\First\wordb}%
\xdef\distanceB{\expandafter\Second\wordb}%
\xdef\angleC{\expandafter\First\wordc}%
\xdef\distanceC{\expandafter\Second\wordc}%
\xdef\angleD{\expandafter\First\wordd}%
\xdef\distanceD{\expandafter\Second\wordd}%
\begin{scope}[shift=(PotatoCenter)]
\draw[#1,smooth,samples=50] plot[variable=\x,domain=\angleA:\angleB] %
(\x:{interpolator(\x,\angleA,\angleB,\distanceA,\distanceB)})
-- 
plot[variable=\x,domain=\angleB:\angleC] %
(\x:{interpolator(\x,\angleB,\angleC,\distanceB,\distanceC)})
--
plot[variable=\x,domain=\angleC:\angleD] %
(\x:{interpolator(\x,\angleC,\angleD,\distanceC,\distanceD)})
--
plot[variable=\x,domain=\angleD:{\angleA+360}] %
(\x:{interpolator(\x,\angleD,{\angleA+360},\distanceD,\distanceA)});
\end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
potato & potato (ordering) \\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-1,1);
\coordinate (B) at (3,0.5);
\coordinate (C) at (4,-1);
\coordinate (D) at (1,-1);
\foreach \p in {A,B,C,D}
{\draw[fill=black] (\p) circle (1pt);}
\DrawPotato[blue]{A}{B}{C}{D}
\draw[red] plot[smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates{(A) (B) (C) (D)};
\end{tikzpicture}& 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-1,1);
\coordinate (B) at (3,0.5);
\coordinate (C) at (4,-1);
\coordinate (D) at (1,-1);
\foreach \p in {A,B,C,D}
{\draw[fill=black] (\p) circle (1pt);}
\DrawPotato[blue]{A}{C}{B}{D}
\draw[purple] plot[smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates{(A) (C) (B) (D)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
filled potato&filled peanut\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-1,1);
\coordinate (B) at (3,0.5);
\coordinate (C) at (4,-1);
\coordinate (D) at (1,-1);
\foreach \p in {A,B,C,D}
{\draw[fill=black] (\p) circle (1pt);}
\DrawPotato[fill=blue]{A}{C}{B}{D}
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-1,1);
\coordinate (B) at (2,0.5);
\coordinate (C) at (4,-1);
\coordinate (D) at (1,-1);
\foreach \p in {A,B,C,D}
{\draw[fill=black] (\p) circle (1pt);}
\DrawPotato[blue,fill=red]{A}{B}{C}{D}
\begin{scope}[closed hobby]
\draw[thick] plot  coordinates{(A) (B) (C) (D)};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is not hard to see that the code is a real mess, but it does roughly what I want, namely it draws potatoes defined by the extreme points (marked by black bullets). For comparison (comparisons are never fair;-) I also draw the results of the above-mentioned smooth plots. My real question is how one can make things simpler, most importantly

- the angular ordering of the coordinates,
- my way of making the shapes "fillable" is certainly not optimal,
- the parsing of the ordered coordinates to a macro that accepts an arbitrary number of points (i.e. 4 or more points). Any comments are highly welcome.

**EDIT**: Added the output of the Hobby algorithm in the peanut figure for comparison.

**UPDATE**: Corrected "potatoe". It is clear to me that with some fair amount of additional adjustments one can recreate these shapes with  smooth plots or Hobby plots. However, the aim here is to avoid these additional adjustments. Of course, if someone could point me to a dictionary that allows me to translate the potato code into Hobby language, that would be great.

**SECOND UPDATE**: I added a simple animation that illustrates what the code does so far.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\makeatletter % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283273/121799
% Here we define the comparison macro for pairs (a,b)
% We assume decimal numbers acceptable to \ifdim tests
\long\def\xintdothis #1#2\xintorthat #3{\fi #1}%
\let\xintorthat \@firstofone

\long\def\@thirdoffour  #1#2#3#4{#3}%
\long\def\@fourthoffour #1#2#3#4{#4}%

\def\IfFirstPairIsGreaterTF #1#2{\@IfFirstPairIsGreaterTF #1,#2,}%

\def\@IfFirstPairIsGreaterTF #1,#2,#3,#4,{%
    \ifdim #1\p@=#3\p@
       \xintdothis{%
         \ifdim #2\p@>#4\p@\expandafter\@firstoftwo
         \else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}\fi
    \ifdim #1\p@>#3\p@\expandafter\@thirdoffour
                      \else\expandafter\@fourthoffour\fi
    \xintorthat{}%
}%

% not needed for numerical inputs
% \catcode`! 3
% \catcode`? 3

% Here there is a very strange \romannumeral0\romannumeral0, this is
% due to some convoluted scheme to avoid double spaces or no spaces
% in between coordinate pairs. Trust me.
\def\QSpairs {\romannumeral0\romannumeral0\qspairs }%
% first we check if empty list
\def\qspairs   #1{\expandafter\qspairs@a\romannumeral-`0#1(!)(?)}%
\def\qspairs@a #1(#2{\ifx!#2\expandafter\qspairs@abort\else
                        \expandafter\qspairs@b\fi (#2}%
\edef\qspairs@abort #1(?){\space\space}%
%
% we check if empty of single and if not pick up the first as Pivot:
\def\qspairs@b #1(#2)#3(#4){\ifx?#4\xintdothis\qspairs@empty\fi
                   \ifx!#4\xintdothis\qspairs@single\fi
                   \xintorthat \qspairs@separate {}{}{#2}(#4)}%
\def\qspairs@empty  #1(?){ }%
\edef\qspairs@single #1#2#3#4(?){\space\space(#3)}%
\def\qspairs@separate #1#2#3#4(#5)%
{%
    \ifx!#5\expandafter\qspairs@separate@done\fi
    \IfFirstPairIsGreaterTF {#5}{#3}%
          \qspairs@separate@appendtogreater
          \qspairs@separate@appendtosmaller {#5}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}%
%
\def\qspairs@separate@appendtogreater #1#2{\qspairs@separate {#2 (#1)}}%
\def\qspairs@separate@appendtosmaller #1#2#3{\qspairs@separate {#2}{#3 (#1)}}%
%
\def\qspairs@separate@done\IfFirstPairIsGreaterTF #1#2%
    \qspairs@separate@appendtogreater
    \qspairs@separate@appendtosmaller #3#4#5#6(?)%
{%
    \expandafter\qspairs@f\expandafter
    {\romannumeral0\qspairs@b #4(!)(?)}{\qspairs@b #5(!)(?)}{ (#2)}%
}%
%
\def\qspairs@f #1#2#3{#2#3#1}%
%
% \catcode`! 12
% \catcode`? 12

\makeatother
\makeatletter % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412901/121799
\newcommand{\Distance}[3]{% % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56353/121799
\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone($#1-#2$)\relax  
\pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{veclen(\the\pgf@x,\the\pgf@y)/28.45274}
}
\makeatother 
\newcount\nbofwords
\makeatletter% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12819/121799
\def\myutil@empty{}
\def\multiwords#1 #2\@nil{% 
 \def\NextArg{#2}%
 \advance\nbofwords by  1 %   
 \expandafter\edef\csname word\@alph\nbofwords\endcsname{#1}% 
 \ifx\myutil@empty\NextArg
     \let\next\@gobble
 \fi
 \next#2\@nil
}%    
\def\GetWords#1{%
   \let\next\multiwords 
   \nbofwords=0 %
   \expandafter\next#1 \@nil %
}% 
\makeatother

\long\def\First(#1,#2){#1}
\long\def\Second(#1,#2){#2}
\tikzset{declare
function={interpolator(\x,\xmin,\xmax,\rmin,\rmax)=(\rmin+\rmax)/2+((\rmin-\rmax)/2)*cos((\x-\xmin)*(180/(\xmax-\xmin)));}}
%\tikzset{declare function={PotatoeRadius(\x,\angleA,\angleB,\angleC,\angleD,\distanceA,\distanceB,\distanceC,\distanceD)=\distanceA+(\x-\angleA)*((\distanceB-\distanceA)/(\angleB-\angleA)+(\x-\angleB)*(((-1)*((\distanceB-\distanceA)/(\angleB-\angleA))+(\distanceC-\distanceB)/(\angleC-\angleB))/(\angleC-\angleA)+(((-1)*(((-1)*((\distanceB-\distanceA)/(\angleB-\angleA))+(\distanceC-\distanceB)/(\angleC-\angleB))/(\angleC-\angleA))+((-1)*((\distanceC-\distanceB)/(\angleC-\angleB))+(\distanceD-\distanceC)/(\angleD-\angleC))/(\angleD-\angleB))*(\x-\angleC))/(\angleD-\angleA)));}}
%(\angleC*(\angleC-\angleD)*\angleD*((\distanceA-\distanceB)*(\angleC-\x)*(\angleD-\x)*\x+pow(\angleA,3)*(-(\angleC*pow(\angleD,2)*\distanceB)+\angleD*(\distanceB-\distanceC)*(\angleD-\x)*\x+\angleC*(\distanceB-\distanceD)*pow(\x,2)+pow(\angleC,2)*(\angleD*\distanceB+(-\distanceB+\distanceD)*\x))+pow(\angleB,3)*(-(\angleA*pow(\angleD,2)*\distanceC)-\angleD*(\distanceA-\distanceC)*(\angleD-\x)*\x+\angleA*(\distanceC-\distanceD)*pow(\x,2)+pow(\angleC,2)*(-(\angleD*\distanceA)+\angleA*\distanceD+\distanceA*\x-\distanceD*\x)+pow(\angleA,2)*(\angleD*\distanceC-\distanceC*\x+\distanceD*\x)+\angleC*(pow(\angleD,2)*\distanceA-pow(\angleA,2)*\distanceD+(-\distanceA+\distanceD)*pow(\x,2)))+pow(\angleA,2)*(-(\angleD*(\distanceB-\distanceC)*(\angleD-\x)*\x*(\angleD+\x))-pow(\angleC,3)*(\angleD*\distanceB+(-\distanceB+\distanceD)*\x)+\angleC*(pow(\angleD,3)*\distanceB+(-\distanceB+\distanceD)*pow(\x,3)))+\angleA*(pow(\angleD,2)*(\distanceB-\distanceC)*(\angleD-\x)*pow(\x,2)+pow(\angleC,3)*(pow(\angleD,2)*\distanceB+(-\distanceB+\distanceD)*pow(\x,2))-pow(\angleC,2)*(pow(\angleD,3)*\distanceB+(-\distanceB+\distanceD)*pow(\x,3)))+pow(\angleB,2)*(\angleD*(\distanceA-\distanceC)*(\angleD-\x)*\x*(\angleD+\x)+pow(\angleC,3)*(\angleD*\distanceA-\angleA*\distanceD-\distanceA*\x+\distanceD*\x)-pow(\angleA,3)*(\angleD*\distanceC+(-\distanceC+\distanceD)*\x)+\angleC*(-(pow(\angleD,3)*\distanceA)+pow(\angleA,3)*\distanceD+(\distanceA-\distanceD)*pow(\x,3))+\angleA*(pow(\angleD,3)*\distanceC+(-\distanceC+\distanceD)*pow(\x,3)))+\angleB*(-(pow(\angleD,2)*(\distanceA-\distanceC)*(\angleD-\x)*pow(\x,2))+pow(\angleC,3)*(-(pow(\angleD,2)*\distanceA)+pow(\angleA,2)*\distanceD+(\distanceA-\distanceD)*pow(\x,2))+pow(\angleA,3)*(pow(\angleD,2)*\distanceC+(-\distanceC+\distanceD)*pow(\x,2))+pow(\angleC,2)*(pow(\angleD,3)*\distanceA-pow(\angleA,3)*\distanceD+(-\distanceA+\distanceD)*pow(\x,3))-pow(\angleA,2)*(pow(\angleD,3)*\distanceC+(-\distanceC+\distanceD)*pow(\x,3))))/((\angleA-\angleB)*(\angleA-\angleC)*(\angleB-\angleC)*(\angleA-\angleD)*(\angleB-\angleD)*(\angleC-\angleD)));}}
\newcommand{\DrawArcAngle}[6][]{% just for emergencies
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
\xdef\angleA{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#4}{center}}
\xdef\angleB{\pgfmathresult}
\draw[#1] ($(#3)+(\angleA:#5)$) arc [start angle=\angleA,end angle=\angleB,radius=#5]
#6;
}
\newcommand{\DrawPotato}[5][]{
\coordinate (PotatoCenter) at (barycentric cs:#2=1,#3=1,#4=1,#5=1);
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{PotatoCenter}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
\xdef\angleA{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{PotatoCenter}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}}
\xdef\angleB{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{PotatoCenter}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#4}{center}}
\xdef\angleC{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{PotatoCenter}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#5}{center}}
\xdef\angleD{\pgfmathresult}

\Distance{(PotatoCenter)}{(#2)}{\distanceA}
\Distance{(PotatoCenter)}{(#3)}{\distanceB}
\Distance{(PotatoCenter)}{(#4)}{\distanceC}
\Distance{(PotatoCenter)}{(#5)}{\distanceD}
\xdef\coordList{(\angleA,\distanceA) (\angleB,\distanceB) (\angleC,\distanceC) (\angleD,\distanceD)}%
\typeout{\coordList}
\xdef\sortedList{\QSpairs{\coordList}}%
\GetWords{\sortedList}
\xdef\NewList{\worda,\wordb,\wordc,\wordd}%
\xdef\NewList{\expandafter\First\worda/\expandafter\Second\worda, 
\expandafter\First\wordb/\expandafter\Second\wordb,
\expandafter\First\wordc/\expandafter\Second\wordc,
\expandafter\First\wordd/\expandafter\Second\wordd}% this list is not used
\xdef\angleA{\expandafter\First\worda}%
\xdef\distanceA{\expandafter\Second\worda}%
\xdef\angleB{\expandafter\First\wordb}%
\xdef\distanceB{\expandafter\Second\wordb}%
\xdef\angleC{\expandafter\First\wordc}%
\xdef\distanceC{\expandafter\Second\wordc}%
\xdef\angleD{\expandafter\First\wordd}%
\xdef\distanceD{\expandafter\Second\wordd}%
\begin{scope}[shift=(PotatoCenter)]
\draw[#1,smooth,samples=50] plot[variable=\x,domain=\angleA:\angleB] %
(\x:{interpolator(\x,\angleA,\angleB,\distanceA,\distanceB)})
-- 
plot[variable=\x,domain=\angleB:\angleC] %
(\x:{interpolator(\x,\angleB,\angleC,\distanceB,\distanceC)})
--
plot[variable=\x,domain=\angleC:\angleD] %
(\x:{interpolator(\x,\angleC,\angleD,\distanceC,\distanceD)})
--
plot[variable=\x,domain=\angleD:{\angleA+360}] %
(\x:{interpolator(\x,\angleD,{\angleA+360},\distanceD,\distanceA)});
\end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{What does the current code do?}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[use as bounding box] (-5,-3) rectangle (7,5);
\node[text width=8cm] (text) at (0,3){%
\only<1>{input: four points, here A, B, C \& D}
\only<2>{step one: compute the barycenter of those points}
\only<3>{imagine now a circle around the barycenter with radius equal to the 
average distance}
\only<4>{the code simply adds some sine functions to the radius such that the
contour runs through the points and the distance is extremal at those points}
\only<5>{however, the code is extremely clumsy and slow, and I have the feeling
that I'm re--inventing the wheel when dealing with lists etc.}
};
\coordinate (A) at (-1,1);
\coordinate (B) at (2,0.5);
\coordinate (C) at (4,-1);
\coordinate (D) at (1,-1);
\coordinate (Center) at (barycentric cs:A=1,B=1,C=1,D=1);
\pgfmathsetmacro{\TotalDistance}{0}
\xdef\DistanceList{}
\foreach \p in {A,B,C,D}
{\draw[fill=black] (\p) circle (1pt) node[below]{\p};
}
\Distance{(Center)}{(A)}{\DistanceA}
\Distance{(Center)}{(B)}{\DistanceB}
\Distance{(Center)}{(C)}{\DistanceC}
\Distance{(Center)}{(D)}{\DistanceD}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\AverageDistance}{(\DistanceA+\DistanceB+\DistanceC+\DistanceD)/4}
\pause
\draw[fill=black] (Center) circle (1pt) node[below]{Center};
\pause
\draw[-,dashed] (Center) circle (\AverageDistance);
\pause
\only<4->{
\DrawPotato[blue]{A}{B}{C}{D}
}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why not using hobby library

Comment: @percusse I do not think that hobby does that, or does it? I thought it does a (polynomial and smooth) interpolation through the points.

Comment: I have no idea what your long complex code does. Why can you not just draw the shape with control points? See answer by @Mark Wibrow on how to easily make a smooth closed curve: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255258/8650

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to read Hobby's docs and use the stuff it provides? You're not using any of the keys which allow you to influence the curves drawn. At least, I don't think so. 'potato' not 'potatoe' by the way ;).

Comment: There is no hobby language you just draw the points and it adjusts the smooth connections. I probably don't understand the goal here.

Comment: @percusse The real aim of this question is to learn some more tricks to avoid the messy parts of the code. And the aim of the code is to avoid to get drowned in parameters and options. You know probably  better than me that there are tons of "Please draw this for me" questions, and the answers are often rather lengthy. My aim is to provide simple command that allows us to answer these questions and the users to modify them without going to too much pain. At the moment, the above code is precisely the opposite.

Comment: Yes but what is the goal, I get four points and then what do I do which shape what parametrization? Right now you only have your way but there is no detail about what you want

Comment: @percusse Now it is me who does not understand the question. Do you want me to describe the above "algorithm" in pictures and formulae? I mainly want to get some feedback on how to elegantly deal with lists of coordinates, i.e. sort them and so on.

Comment: If I have (1,1) (1,0) (0,1) (0,0) what needs to happen? There are a lot of stuff in your question but there is no details on what you want. You are missing the specifications. "at which the distance to the barycenter of the shape is extremal" I don't know what this means.

Comment: @percusse It's all in the code. Essentially, in polar coordinates, it draws a smooth shape that runs through all points such that these are extremal. Imagine drawing a circle with radius equal to average distance, and then adding sin and cos functions to the radius such that the contour runs through the points.

Comment: @marmot Again one last time. What has to happen given those points? Shapes that have those extremal points are not unique. You don't have anything regarding specs but a lot of handwaving. Which contour? with which in out angles what is smoothness

Comment: @percusse Sorry, above is an explicit code that precisely does what it should. How is that "handwaving"? How can I be more explicit? As explained in the question and in the comments, it draw a "circle" with smoothly varying radius such that those four points are at extremal positions. If you don't like the question, that's perfectly fine, but from my perspective I've done everything I could to describe the algorithm by spelling it out. The question is about its implementation (sorting lists and so on).

Comment: fine as you wish. I don't mind. if you ask a question, you need others to understand it to get an answer. I'm not going to read your code if I don't know what it is supposed to do. Use your own code then

Comment: @percusse I don't think there is any reason to exchange such messages. If you could kindly tell me what to do, I'd be happy to do it. So far I've not seen any specific request, only that you do not understand what the code is supposed to do. Should I post a graphical illustration? (Again, the code itself works, it is just super ugly. And given that Ti*k*Z creates lists and sorts them internally, as in the case of intersections, I was hoping that someone could point me to a trick that allows me to access these tools.)

Comment: @percusse I cannot read your mind, but I added something which you might have wanted me to do.

Comment: Isn't this a lot of fuss to go to to draw potatoes and peanuts? Why those? `tikzducks` I get, but `tikzpotoesandpeanuts` not so much. Of course, there's no reason you shouldn't: it is no more specialised than ducks or cats or cauldrons, after all. But your spin about answering questions suggests you think there is a large potential user base and I'm not sure people are that keen on tubers and legumes. Of course, I might be wrong. To put this another way: I have no idea what you are trying to do. What problem does your code solve? When you wrote it, what were you trying to get it to do?

Comment: @cfr You might be right in that the potatoes themselves are not really worth the effort. The real question behind that is: Ti*k*Z does all these amazing things with intersections, where it has internally a list and sorts it and so on and so forth. Why is it so freaking difficult to do something similar? Do we really need to load xparse or even use lualatex? Of course, I could try to marry this code to intersections or something the like. But I feel that there must be a simpler way....

Comment: ... and as for your question, I really only wanted to provide a simple means allowing one to draw all the irregular shapes we are all too familiar with. Do I know that this is the best approach? No. Can this be also done with smooth plots or the hobby library? Certainly, but I would like to argue that finding the relevant input there is less intuitive than with the above code. And yes, I am aware that this is a subjective statement, but I feel that at least I would be able to draw some of the irregular shapes more efficiently.

Comment: Good. So can you articulate your alternative approach in English? How do you want the code to enable the drawing of irregular shapes exactly? The user gives some input - what? a list of coordinates? - and then the code does what with them? For Hobby, the simple case would be something like 'construct a smooth path through the specified coordinates, in the order given'. Can you give an equivalent specification for your code?

Comment: @cfr At present, I do not want to change the contour at all. All I want is to replace the mess that draws it by something more elegant.

Comment: But how can you get help replacing it if we don't know what it is meant to do? That's what you're not telling us.

Comment: @cfr Well, the contour should be what it is. The way to get this contour is a mess. Apart from the fact that the code takes very long to compile, I'd like to get some insights on how to deal with these lists more appropriately. If the answer is that it is impossible without learning completely new things (LaTeX 3, xparse), that's also fine.

Comment: I have no idea what the answer is. I don't even understand the question. You haven't said what the code is supposed to do with the input. Apparently, it involves lists. Beyond that, I'm in the dark.

Comment: @cfr Sorry if the question is unclear. Is it clearer if I say that I'd like to see an elegant code that draws shapes similar to those above when 4 coordinates are specified, and that can take n coordinates?

Comment: Why is not `\draw[use Hobby shortcut,closed,tension=3] (A) .. (B) .. (C) .. (D);` good enough to draw potatoes if the points are cyclically ordered ? And if it is, the only question should be how to order them in a cyclic order, no ? Or may be you don't like the hobby "smoothing" and you prefer [spiral splins](http://www.levien.com/phd/thesis.pdf) ?

Comment: @Kpym No, I want to draw the "potato" by defining the extrema, as explained in the post.

Comment: I think that if you want`Simple command that allows us to answer "Please draw this for me" questions` and that use your particular algorithm you should write a library (named `potatos`). Calculating the barycenter and ordering clockwise the points is complex enough to be considered as "simple".

Comment: @Kpym Many things that Ti*k*Z does internally is not simple. If you write a command that does complex operations internally, who cares? My question is not on the algorithm but on a more elegant treatment of the lists and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `math` and `calc` libraries, it's possible to do it slightly simpler. You can flip any two coordinates to see that it also works for coordinates that are not already ordered (I only tested flipping `A` and `B` but it should work for all of them).

I didn't change anything between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` so `\Distance` is still there, but I don't use it in my definition of `\DrawPotato` so you don't really need it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,math}

% I don't use this in my \DrawPotato
\makeatletter % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412901/121799
\newcommand{\Distance}[3]{% % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56353/121799
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone($#1-#2$)\relax  
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{veclen(\the\pgf@x,\the\pgf@y)/28.45274}
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
    declare function={
        interpolator(\x,\xmin,\xmax,\rmin,\rmax)=
            1/28.4527*((\rmin+\rmax)/2+((\rmin-\rmax)/2)*cos((\x-\xmin)*(180/(\xmax-\xmin))));
    }
}

\newcommand\DrawPotato[5][]{%
    \tikzmath{
        coordinate \p,\cent;
        \p0 = {(#2)};
        \p1 = {(#3)};
        \p2 = {(#4)};
        \p3 = {(#5)};
        \cent = ({(\px0+\px1+\px2+\px3)/4},{(\py0+\py1+\py2+\py3)/4}); % Average point
        real \angl,\dist;
        int \i,\j;
        for \i in {0,1,2,3}{
            \angl{\i} = atan2(\py{\i}-\centy,\px{\i}-\centx);
            \dist{\i} = veclen(\py{\i}-\centy,\px{\i}-\centx);
        };
        for \i in {0,1,2,3}{
            for \j in {0,1,2,3}{
                if min(\angl{0},\angl{1},\angl{2},\angl{3}) == \angl{\j} then {
                    \sortang{\i} = \angl{\j};
                    \sortind{\i} = \j;
                };
            };
            \angl{\sortind{\i}} = 500; % Arbitrary large value
            \sortdis{\i} = \dist{\sortind{\i}};
        };
    }
    \draw[#1,smooth,samples=50,shift={(\cent)}] 
        plot[variable=\x,domain=\sortang{0}:\sortang{1}] %
            (\x:{interpolator(\x,{\sortang{0}},{\sortang{1}},{\sortdis{0}},{\sortdis{1}})}) --
        plot[variable=\x,domain=\sortang{1}:\sortang{2}] %
            (\x:{interpolator(\x,{\sortang{1}},{\sortang{2}},{\sortdis{1}},{\sortdis{2}})}) --
        plot[variable=\x,domain=\sortang{2}:\sortang{3}] %
            (\x:{interpolator(\x,{\sortang{2}},{\sortang{3}},{\sortdis{2}},{\sortdis{3}})}) --
        plot[variable=\x,domain=\sortang{3}:\sortang{0}+360] %
            (\x:{interpolator(\x,{\sortang{3}},{\sortang{0}+360},{\sortdis{3}},{\sortdis{0}})}) --
        cycle ;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{What does the current code do?}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[use as bounding box] (-5,-3) rectangle (7,5);
\node[text width=8cm] (text) at (0,3){%
\only<1>{input: four points, here A, B, C \& D}
\only<2>{step one: compute the barycenter of those points}
\only<3>{imagine now a circle around the barycenter with radius equal to the 
average distance}
\only<4>{the code simply adds some sine functions to the radius such that the
contour runs through the points and the distance is extremal at those points}
\only<5>{however, the code is extremely clumsy and slow, and I have the feeling
that I'm re--inventing the wheel when dealing with lists etc.}
};
\coordinate (A) at (-1,1);
\coordinate (B) at (2,0.5);
\coordinate (C) at (4,-1);
\coordinate (D) at (1,-1);
\coordinate (Center) at (barycentric cs:A=1,B=1,C=1,D=1);
\pgfmathsetmacro{\TotalDistance}{0}
\xdef\DistanceList{}
\foreach \p in {A,B,C,D}
{\draw[fill=black] (\p) circle (1pt) node[below]{\p};
}
\Distance{(Center)}{(A)}{\DistanceA}
\Distance{(Center)}{(B)}{\DistanceB}
\Distance{(Center)}{(C)}{\DistanceC}
\Distance{(Center)}{(D)}{\DistanceD}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\AverageDistance}{(\DistanceA+\DistanceB+\DistanceC+\DistanceD)/4}
\pause
\draw[fill=black] (Center) circle (1pt) node[below]{Center};
\pause
\draw[-,dashed] (Center) circle (\AverageDistance);
\pause
\only<4->{
\DrawPotato[blue]{A}{B}{C}{D}
}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, also for looking at this ancient question! ;-)

Comment: @marmot It was my pleasure :) maybe we could automate it to accept more or less points.

Comment: Yes, maybe. I am still wondering if there is some means (built in Ti*k*Z) to sort lists according to some entry. (I guess now I would not ask the question in this form any more but I am really grateful for your answer!)

Comment: @marmot Yes I think you could ask that as a separate question. I don't know of any way, but I'm not really a Ti*k*zpert.

Comment: You are a Ti*k*Zpert but I did not mean to bug you with an additional request. Please do not spend more time on this, I am very happy with your nice answer!

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the `coordinate \p,\cent;` does inside the tikzmath command? I'm not able to find any documentation on it...

Comment: It defines the two macros as coordinates, it's documented in section 58.3 of the [pgf manual](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=706).