# Multiple Lists by Alphabetical Order at End of Document

Tags: lists, indexing, thmtools, alphabet

I want to get the following lists, but I do not know how. I have investigated several approaches, but none led me to the desired result. I basically want my document to have several lists at the end. Essentially, I want (1) a list of definitions, (2) a list of propositions and (3) a list of figures. However, I want:

(1) All the lists to have the same exact format.
(2) Alphabetical order in all the lists.
(3) No pagebreaks between the lists.
(4) A smaller font than the font in the main text for all the lists.
(5) No number in the entries of the list.
(6) Two-columns in the lists.
(7) Small vertical spacing in between the entries of the list.

Suppose that you have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools, amsthm}
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\normalfont\bfseries, notefont=\bfseries, bodyfont=\normalfont, shaded={rulecolor=black,rulewidth=0.5pt,bgcolor={rgb}{1,1,1},margin=5pt,textwidth=11.8cm}, notebraces={}{:}, headpunct={}, postheadspace=1em]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{proposition}
\declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\normalfont\bfseries, numbered=no, notefont=\bfseries, bodyfont=\footnotesize, shaded={rulecolor=gray,rulewidth=0.5pt,bgcolor={rgb}{1,1,1},margin=5pt,textwidth=11.8cm}, qed=\qedsymbol, notebraces={--- }{:}, headpunct={}, postheadspace=1em]{mystyle5}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle5]{proof}
\declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\normalfont\bfseries, shaded={rulecolor=black,rulewidth=0.5pt,margin=5pt,textwidth=11.8cm}, notebraces={}{:}, headpunct={}, postheadspace=1em]{mystyle3}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle3]{definition}

\numberwithin{proposition}{section}
\numberwithin{definition}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\Roman{figure}.}
\renewcommand{\thedefinition}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\Alph{definition}.}
\renewcommand{\theproposition}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{proposition}.}

\begin{document}
\begin{proposition}[\textbf{WHATEVER1}]
    BLABLABLA   
\end{proposition}
\begin{proposition}[\textbf{WHATEVER2}]
    BLABLABLA   
\end{proposition}
\begin{definition}[\textbf{LOL1}]
    LOREM IPSUM 
\end{definition}
\begin{proposition}[\textbf{WHATEVER3}]
    BLABLABLA   
\end{proposition}
\begin{proposition}[\textbf{WHATEVER4}]
    BLABLABLA   
\end{proposition}
\begin{definition}[\textbf{LOL2}]
    LOREM IPSUM 
\end{definition}
\begin{definition}[\textbf{LOL3}]
    LOREM IPSUM 
\end{definition}
\begin{proposition}[\textbf{WHATEVER5}]
    BLABLABLA   
\end{proposition}
\begin{proposition}[\textbf{WHATEVER6}]
    BLABLABLA   
\end{proposition} 
\begin{definition}[\textbf{LOL4}]
    LOREM IPSUM 
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

How would you generate the desired output? If you know how to achieve some (even if not all) of my goals, please share it! Thank you all!

Comment: Generally the makeindex program is used to alphabetize, but it can be done directly.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273037/expandable-quick-sort-array-macro

Comment: As soon as I have time, I'll check makeindex again. The latter manual approach you propose requires a Tex expertise I don't have, I'm afraid.

Comment: take a look at the `imakeidx` package.  it uses the `makeindex` program, but provides an easy and logical way to create multiple indexes.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thanks for your suggestion. However, I have throughly tried and there is no way that     imakeidx produces any output for me. I have been searching and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: you haven't "saved" any information that can be retrieved and manipulated later.  i still recomment `imakeidx`, with entries identifying the "section" and the entry text.  for example, for the first proposition: `\index{2 Whatever1@Whatever1}` where the "2" at the beginning of the sort field indicates the order of the grouping.  you'd need to insert an explicit heading for each group; if you like this approach, i can work more on the segmentation.