# Creating a multi-labeled question bank with xsim/exam

Tags: exam, exercises, xsim

I want to make a question bank on functional equations problems (in mathematical olympiads) using `xsim` or `exam` (or any other) packages.

The number of the questions is huge (around 3000) and I have 10 `.tex` files, each of which contains a portion of the problems (around 300 in each file). My goal is to label the problems with (say) three labels `domain=R`, `domain=Q`, and `domain=Z`, and then use the sub-labels `cauchy-based` or `jensen-based` for each of the labels, so that in the end I would have 6 different categories of problems. Then I want to print all problems in each of these categories in a separate chapter of a book.

I found [a very similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/340727/48840) on TeX.SE but it doesn't have any answers. I skimmed through `xsim` and `exam` documentations and the closest thing I've found is [this example](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xsim/doc/examples/xsim.texsx-305110.tex) from `xsim`, but that doesn't do what I want.

I would be really happy to hear some suggestions. Maybe there is a mysterious package that I don't know of? Please help me! Thanks.

Comment: [Crosspost](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=105539#p105539)

Comment: You can use \csname ...\endcsname to effectively implement arrays with LaTeX (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273037/expandable-quick-sort-array-macro/273476?s=5|16.8414#273476 for example).

Answer (score 1):

> I skimmed through `xsim` and `exam` documentations and the closest thing I've found is this example from `xsim`, but that doesn't do what I want.

Actually this is quite easy with `xsim`. (Of course the manual cannot contain examples for all different kinds of applications.) Here is a small example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\DeclareExerciseTagging{domain}
\DeclareExerciseTagging{base}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-exercises.tex}
\begin{exercise}[domain=Z,base=cauchy]
  one
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[domain=Z,base=jensen]
  two
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[domain=Q,base=cauchy]
  three
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[domain=Q,base=jensen]
  four
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[domain=R,base=cauchy]
  five
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[domain=R,base=jensen]
  six
\end{exercise}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\section{A}
\xsimsetup{base=cauchy,domain=R}
\input{\jobname-exercises.tex}% exercise five

\section{B}
\xsimsetup{base=jensen,domain=Z}
\input{\jobname-exercises.tex}% exercise two

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

PS: if you have such a large number of exercises `xsim` is probably quite slow in the processing. Also I'd strongly suggest to make use of `xsim`'s `path` option.