# sorting text file in plain TeX

Tags: plain-tex, sorting, amstex

I have seen Latex sort macros (for an index, which is precisely what I want, the index having several thousand entries); but I haven't seen one in plain (or AmS-TeX, for that matter; either is OK). Can someone point me to one?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The usual way of sorting an index with LaTeX (I'm sure it is adaptable to plain) is to call an external program (makeindex or xindy) for that matter. Why would you want to do it on macro level?

Comment: I am used to tables of contents (for which I managed to write macros for plain, writing to toc files); these update themselves (after an additional compile), and I hope to do the same with the indexes. I have never used makeindex or xindy; do these run in plain, and update themselves as changes are made to the tex files?

Comment: The manpage of makeindex suggests it can do so. Naturally you would have to write the typical interfacing macros but at least sorting would be more efficient. And updating itself is not quite understandable, as an external tool it has to be called. You could automate this by using a build tool like arara, but that's independent from the choice of external tools.

Comment: I should add that I have done indexing before, but only by writing all the index entries to a file, sorting the resulting text file in something like TeX-edit (despite its name, unrelated to TeX), and then by hand, consolidating multiple entries. Naturally, any change in the document will affect this, so I wait until the very end to do this (once).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273037/expandable-quick-sort-array-macro/273476?r=SearchResults&s=1|30.5805#273476  There may be some LaTeX command, but it is mostly base TeX.

Comment: Here is an older article http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb14-3/tb40laan-sort.pdf by Kees van der Laan; it uses only `plain \TeX` macros.

Comment: @UdoWermuth Thank you! At least one them is very close to what I want, if rather complex (which is probably necessary). I will try it out.

Comment: Eplain can work with makeindex. Is `eplain` an option you can use? To use eplain, 
 have `\input eplain` at the beginning of a plain tex document.