# pgfplots add xtick from array

Tags: pgfplots, labels, axis

I have `\points` array and I want to add `xtick` and `ytick` on my axis automatically from it. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\points{{{-9,0.30},{-6,0.44},{-2,0.59},{3,1}}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\len}{dim(\points)-1}

\begin{axis}
[
axis lines = center,
axis line style = thick,
% xtick= loop here for \points[\i][0]
% ytick= loop here for \points[\i][1] where \i=0,...,\len
clip=false
]
\addplot ({x},{x^2});
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the problem was about generating this kind of array `{<num1>, <num2>, <num3>, ...}`. It occurred to be quite tricky, but I managed to find the solution.

The key to solve the problem is an [expansion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451/213149). `\xdef`(equivalent to `\global\edef`) allows to define an expanded macro so that I it can access itself in its definition. For example

```
\edef\foo{-3}     % -> -3
\edef\foo{\foo,6} % -> -3,6
```

---

First solution based on `\push` macros that I found in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/273037/213149). And the following code forms the desired array

```
\def\push#1#2{\expandafter\xdef\csname #1\endcsname{\expandafter\ifx\csname #1\endcsname\empty\else\csname #1\endcsname,\fi#2}}

\def\xarr{}
\def\yarr{}
\foreach \i [evaluate={\x=\points[\i][0]; \y=\points[\i][1]}] in {0,...,\len}{
    \push{xarr}{\x}
    \push{yarr}{\y}
}
```

Second solution doesn't require that macros, but still based on expanded definition

```
\def\xarr{}
\def\yarr{}
\foreach \i [evaluate={\x=\points[\i][0]; \y=\points[\i][1]; \c=ifthenelse(\i<\len,",",)}] in {0,...,\len}{
    \xdef\xarr{\xarr\x\c}
    \xdef\yarr{\yarr\y\c}
}
```

---

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\points{{{-9,0.30},{-6,0.44},{-2,0.59},{3,1}}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\len}{dim(\points)-1}

\def\push#1#2{\expandafter\xdef\csname #1\endcsname{\expandafter\ifx\csname #1\endcsname\empty\else\csname #1\endcsname,\fi#2}}

\def\xarr{}
\def\yarr{}

% First method
%\foreach \i [evaluate={\x=\points[\i][0]; \y=\points[\i][1]}] in {0,...,\len}{
%    \push{xarr}{\x}
%    \push{yarr}{\y}
%}

% Second method
\foreach \i [evaluate={\x=\points[\i][0]; \y=\points[\i][1]; \c=ifthenelse(\i<\len,",",)}] in {0,...,\len}{
    \xdef\xarr{\xarr\x\c}
    \xdef\yarr{\yarr\y\c}
}

\begin{axis}
[
axis lines = center,
axis line style = thick,
% xtick= loop here for \points[\i][0]
% ytick= loop here for \points[\i][1] where \i=0,...,\len
clip=false
]
\addplot ({x},{x^2});
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that if you have `babel` package added, the second method might throw an error. That's all because of `"` inside `ifthenelse`. In order to fix that, use `ifthenelse(\i<\len,\string",\string",)`, or use `\shorthandoff{"}`.

Answer (score 2):

No need to loop.

The problem is that the points of your MWE have nothing to do with your curve (leave out `opacity=0` to see them), they are neither on the curve nor near the curve, so the graphical representation is not good.
I think it would be better with your actual points and curve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\points{(-9,0.30) (-6,0.44) (-2,0.59) (3,1)}
\begin{axis}[scale=1.5, 
    xtick=data,
    ytick=data,
    axis lines = center,
    axis line style = thick,
    clip=false
    ]
\addplot[only marks, 
    opacity=0] 
    coordinates {\points};
\addplot ({x},{x^2});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But I need to display labels only for those points that are in `\points` array

Comment: @antshar See my renewed answer, please.

Comment: That's an interesting workaround. If you fake ticks with drawings inside `axis` I don't see a reason to give up the initial array. I still don't know a way of converting this one into mine that can be iterated with an access to a specific index. So `\foreach \i [evaluate={\ix=\points[\i][0]; \iy=\points[\i][1];}] in {0,...,\len}{ \addplot [only marks, opacity=0] coordinates {(\ix,0) (0,\iy)}; }` will do.

Comment: @antshar Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean by "give up the initial  array"

Comment: my array of points has `{{{x1,y1},{x2,x2},...}}` format, but yours is `{(x1,y1),(x2,y2),...}`

Comment: @antshar Ah, ok. It is because that is the syntax accepted by coordinates. If you can't change that, my solution is useless

Comment: your workaround with faking ticks is clever. It might be useful for someone else. Personally, I often come across with an interesting approach in posts that don't really relate to my search request, but still contain useful information.

Comment: @antshar Thank you! You're always very kind

Answer (score 1):

Here I use a `\foreach` to loop through `\points` and construct the list of x- and y-coords stored in `\pointsX` and `\pointsY`, respectively. Then just set `xtick=\pointsX` in `axis` environment.

Wrapping all these into a new `pgfkeys` handler would be neat, but the difference between a `\foreach`-list and a `pgfmath`-array makes the generalization very hard.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\points{{{-9,0.30},{-6,0.44},{-2,0.59},{3,1}}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\len}{dim(\points)-1}

\def\pointsX{}
\def\pointsY{}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\len} {
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\points[\i][0]}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\points[\i][1]}
  \ifnum\i=0
    \xappto\pointsX{\x}
    \xappto\pointsY{\y}
  \else
    \xappto\pointsX{,\x}
    \xappto\pointsY{,\y}
  \fi
}

\begin{axis}
[
  axis lines = center,
  axis line style = thick,
  xtick=\pointsX,
  ytick=\pointsY,
  clip=false
]
\addplot ({x},{x^2});
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see, `etoolbox` provides macro that appends elements. That's a neat solution that doesn't require much effort. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @antshar The dependence on `etoolbox` is soft. You can easily define your own  `\xappto` by `\def\myXappto#1#2{\xdef#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}#2}}` (this differs from the `\xappto` that it doesn't check the existance of `#1`).