# Automatically sort the entries in a description environment alphabetically

Tags: description

I want to automatically sort the entries in a description environment alphabetically. I see examples of lists being sorted alphabetically, but I am unable to adapt those examples to work for descriptions. An example of a description list I want to sort is:

```
\begin{description}
\item[AI:] Artificial Intelligence
\item[ML:] Machine Learning
\item[DL:] Deep Learning
\end{description}
```

Comment: This requires three steps.  Fisrt you would need to store each item in an array (\csname).  Then sort the array alphabetically.  Finally format the sorted array elements.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273037/expandable-quick-sort-array-macro

Comment: You can use packages like [`glossaries`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries), [`nomencl`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) etc. to create such lists. Some of them use MakeIndex or Xindy to do the sorting optionally or mandatory. Some provide options to do the MakeIndex run automatically.