How to sort list of abbreviations in LaTeX
I finished writing my thesis and wanted to generate a list of abbreviations at the end of the document. This is my code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{gpc}[GPC]{Gel--Permeations--Chromatographie}

\acro{dsc}[DSC]{Dynamische Differenzkalorimetrie}

\acro{ISISI10}[ISISI\_$10\%$]{Polyisopren--b--Polystyrol Pentablockcopolymer mit $10$ Gw.-$\%$ Styrol}

\acro{ISISI20}[ISISI\_$20\%$]{Polyisopren--b--Polystyrol Pentablockcopolymer mit $20$ Gw.-$\%$ Styrol}

\acro{ISISI40}[ISISI\_$40\%$]{Polyisopren--b--Polystyrol Pentablockcopolymer mit $40$ Gw.-$\%$ Styrol}

\acro{SISIS90}[SISIS\_$90\%$]{Polystyrol--b--Polyisopren Pentablockcopolymer mit $90$ Gw.-$\%$ Styrol}

\acro{SIS10}[SIS\_$10\%$]{Polystyrol--b--Polyisopren Triblockcopolymer mit $10$ Gw.-$\%$ Styrol}

\acro{ISISISI10}[ISISISI\_$10\%$]{Polyisopren--b--Polystyrol Heptablockcopolymer mit $10$ Gw.-$\%$ Styrol}

\acro{ISISISI40}[ISISISI\_$40\%$]{Polyisopren--b--Polystyrol Heptablockcopolymer mit $40$ Gw.-$\%$ Styrol}

\acro{SIS90Blend}[SIS\_$90\%$\_Blend]{Polyisopren--b--Polystyrol Triblockcopolymerblend mit $90$ Gw.-$\%$ Styrol}


\end{acronym}

\end{document}


Is there a way to sort the acronyms alphabetically or do I have to use another package?

You might want to take a look at the acro package.

Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273037/expandable-quick-sort-array-macro although you waould have to figure out how acro stores its entries.  Or create your own package.

acronym does not support any sorting, entries will appear in the order in the source (which you could sort by non-TeX means).
nomencl will produce a sorted list for you, it's probably easiest for just making a sorted list, glossaries and acro can also do that and a lot more to boot (see this answer for a basic example, although the acro portion is now a little out of date.
For nomencl you can easily adapt your code as
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\nomenclature{GPC}{Gel--Permeations--Chromatographie}
\nomenclature{DSC}{Dynamische Differenzkalorimetrie}
\nomenclature{ISISI\_$10\%$}{Polyisopren--b--Polystyrol Pentablockcopolymer mit $10$ Gw.-$\%$ Styrol}
\nomenclature{ISISI\_$20\%$}{Polyisopren--b--Polystyrol Pentablockcopolymer mit $20$ Gw.-$\%$ Styrol}
\nomenclature{ISISI\_$40\%$}{Polyisopren--b--Polystyrol Pentablockcopolymer mit $40$ Gw.-$\%$ Styrol}
\nomenclature{SISIS\_$90\%$}{Polystyrol--b--Polyisopren Pentablockcopolymer mit $90$ Gw.-$\%$ Styrol}
\nomenclature{SIS\_$10\%$}{Polystyrol--b--Polyisopren Triblockcopolymer mit $10$ Gw.-$\%$ Styrol}
\nomenclature{ISISISI\_$10\%$}{Polyisopren--b--Polystyrol Heptablockcopolymer mit $10$ Gw.-$\%$ Styrol}
\nomenclature{ISISISI\_$40\%$}{Polyisopren--b--Polystyrol Heptablockcopolymer mit $40$ Gw.-$\%$ Styrol}
\nomenclature{SIS\_$90\%$\_Blend}{Polyisopren--b--Polystyrol Triblockcopolymerblend mit $90$ Gw.-$\%$ Styrol}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}


However note for symbols you may need to follow Make nomenclature sort math correctly to manually set a string to sort by.

Thank you very much. This was perfect.
With \textbf and \bm I could make the abbreviations bold and with the sort= feature I could even sort greek letters and symbols in a math environement alphabetically.
