how to create variable and use it or something else
on my project (always the same) I have some author names that are always the same (pippo pluto paperino...)
I would use the correct name In a specific place, without edit it, but just inserting the number that correspond to a list of author.
I hope I've explained myself well
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

author(1)=pippo
author(2)=pluto
author(3)=paperino

\begin{document}
bla bla bla bla bla bla

author = author(3)

\end{document}

As already told, the MWE is the solution of the prob.
anywai, I would that if the author is paperino, I just should write the index of author (3)
Renato

minimal working example (MWE)

I don't have MWE,because I need the appropriate code to do that. And this is what I'm looking for. I could do an example:
---listo of author
1 pippo
2 pluto
3 paperino
--- I need to use author paperino
use author 3

You can always make a mwe, even if it is just a simple test document so people willing to invest their free time, don't have to type all the boring things like a document class.

Currently, it is very unclear what you want. Maybe something like a l3 sequence (see interface3.pdf). Maybe only something like \newcommand*\authorA{pippo}\newcommand*{\authorB}{pluto}, or maybe something like an author index (I don't think so, but who knows …) or an enumeration list and just \label{…} for each author to be able to use \ref{…} or something completely different …

Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273037/expandable-quick-sort-array-macro/273476?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C27.9036#273476

It's a bit clearer what you want, but not completely.  Do you want to have \authors=(pippo,pluto,paperino) in the preamble, and then in the document have \author{3} become paperino?  In that case, cabohah's suggestions would be sufficient.  If not, can you explain why not?

I use something that works this way: in the preamble or at the start of the document, I provide a key-value list of abbreviations and author names (actually bibkeys, but that doesn't matter). These are then converted into a set of macros such that a backslash followed by the abbreviation becomes a macro producing the author name. I think this is preferable to numbers for a large number of authors. But if you do want numbers, something like @cabohah's suggestion is simpler.

@Teepeemm: Yes I want that. Set on the preamble a number that correspond to a name of author and in document (after \begin Document I just change the number of author and I have the name of corresponding Author. All this to gaining time. I have to write it every day in a few time. If I can obtain that just changing a number, it could be my goal

One possibility:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\ExpandArgs{c}\NewDocumentCommand{author1}{}{pippo}
\ExpandArgs{c}\NewDocumentCommand{author2}{}{pluto}
\ExpandArgs{c}\NewDocumentCommand{author3}{}{paperino}

\begin{document}

bla bla bla bla bla bla

L'autore è \UseName{author1}, anche se l'idea era di \UseName{author3}.

\end{document}

Or maybe you really also need another level of indirection so that you can change the preamble and not touch anything in the main text:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[italian]{babel} % good idea if you write in Italian

\ExpandArgs{c}\NewDocumentCommand{author1}{}{Pippo}
\ExpandArgs{c}\NewDocumentCommand{author2}{}{Pluto}
\ExpandArgs{c}\NewDocumentCommand{author3}{}{Paperino}
\ExpandArgs{c}\NewDocumentCommand{author4}{}{Paperoga}

% a level of indirection: change here and just use that in
% the rest of the document
\newcommand{\autoreprincipale}{\UseName{author1}}
\newcommand{\autoresecondario}{\UseName{author4}}
% maybe you can look at the package "xspace" (/me ducks)

\begin{document}

bla bla bla bla bla bla

L'autore è \autoreprincipale, anche se l'idea era di 
\autoresecondario{} che non ha voluto essere citato.

bla bla bla

Firmato: \autoreprincipale.

\end{document}


Finally, notice that the example is complicated by the fact that I was using numbers in the definitions (macros) that contain the names, and that forces me to use a workaround because this is not normally permitted in LaTeX (and TeX). If you stick instead to the (quite traditional) way of using roman numerals, the code is much simpler:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[italian]{babel} % good idea if you write in Italian

\newcommand{\authorI}{Pippo}
\newcommand{\authorII}{Pluto}
\newcommand{\authorIII}{Paperino}
\newcommand{\authorIV}{Paperoga}

% a level of indirection: change here and just use that in
% the rest of the document
\newcommand{\autoreprincipale}{\authorI}
\newcommand{\autoresecondario}{\authorIV}
% maybe you can look at the package "xspace" (/me ducks)

\begin{document}

bla bla bla bla bla bla

L'autore è \autoreprincipale, anche se l'idea era di \autoresecondario{} che non ha voluto essere citato.

bla bla bla

Firmato: \autoreprincipale.

\end{document}

which has exactly the same output as before.
